# How do I pass values to this constructor?

Tags: java

I'm working on this assignment but got stuck on this point.

How can a value of (length) and (width) be passed on to this constructor?

UML (RoomDimension bin). If bin is an object.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7zP9.png

My code

```
 public class RoomDimension
{

private double length;
private double width;

public RoomDimension(double len, double w)
{
    length = len;
    width = w;
}

public double getArea()
{
    return (length*width);
}

public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%10s %10s %10s %10s", "Length: ", length, "Width: ", width);
}
}
```

I'm stuck on the part below

```
public class RoomCarpet
     {
    private RoomDimension size;
    private double carpetCost;

    public void RoomCarpet(RoomDimension dim, double cost)
    {
        // how do use the parameter (object dim) to set size?
    }

    public double getTotalCost()
    {
        return (size.getArea())*carpetCost;
    }
     }
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: It's not clear what you mean... can't you just use `size = dim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `assign` dim to `size`

```
 public void RoomCarpet(RoomDimension dim, double cost)
    {
        // how do use the parameter (object dim) to set size?
        this.size = dim;
       // similarly for cost
        this.carpetCost = cost;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.

Comment: one more thing, to test this on a driver program, you need to make a new RoomDimension object and pass it on to RoomCarpet constructor, yes?

Comment: Yes, You will need to create `RoomDimension Object` by passing length and width and then create a bew RoomCarpet with created Dimension

Comment: Kindly accept as answer, if it helped you. Thanks